# What is aes in "operational mode"

Tags: aes, modes-of-operation, terminology

I'm currently reading [this report](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.00384) on the security of the IOT protocol "LoRaWAN".

On page 3, it says the following:

```
LoRaWAN relies on AES cryptography algorithms combined with operational mode
```

Is this an actual mode of operation for AES, in the same way that CBC or ECB is?

Or is it perhaps that the term "operational mode" is often used to describe a certain mode of operation?

Comment: It looks like they indeed meant "mode of operation" - in this case CTR mode seems to be used. The report is simply a combination of different papers of LoRaWAN it seems, without any additional depth, so I'm not surprised if some terms are somewhat mangled. I'm planning a study on the frequency of studies that are an aggregation of previous studies, maybe I should include this one ;)

Comment: That would be really cool! How do you know that they mean CTR? is it just implicit? I had the impression that CBC was more or less the standard

Comment: Further on they list a random set of attacks on CTR such as bit flipping. They also talk about the (short) MAC value though, so yeah...